# Attribute Error when attempting to create a model manager in Django

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I am following the book Django By Example as a tutorial. I am trying to create a custom model manager following the steps in the book but I am having an issue where I am getting an AttributeError.

My models.py file is the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                    self).get_queryset()\
                         .filter(status='published')
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, unique_for_date = 'publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = 'blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'draft')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
    def str(self):
        return self.title
    objects = models.Manager() # default manager
    published = PublishedManager() # customer manager
```

Following the steps in the book I ran:

```
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> Post.published.filter(title__startswith='Who')
```

But following the second command I get the following AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'PublishedManager' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

I understand that I mustn't be defining 'filter' correctly but I am not sure how I do this in this scenario, any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `print(Post.published.__class__.__mro__)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I had the following:
(<class 'blog.models.PublishedManager'>, <class 'django.db.models.base.Model'>, <class 'object'>)

Comment: it looks like `PublishedManager` is a `Model`, not a `Manager`.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not import another `models` in the file, or inherited from `Model` instead?

Comment: I deleted and recreated the published post and that seemed to resolve the issue so not sure what the issue was. Appreciate you taking the time though! Thank you